# Set data validation for column including new rows

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column in a Google spreadsheet with data validation, that makes a drop down menu available when editing existing rows. Occasionally though contributors create new rows at the bottom of the doc and this validation is lost.

I would like to keep this validatation in the column even in newly created rows (excluding the header row).

I have seen much of this discussion throughout stackoverflow and google help forums, but still cannot find a clear answer.

My hunch is that this would involve Google Apps Acript using an `onEdit` trigger and then either paint formatting or a combination of the confusing class DataValidationBuilder. (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) but I'm not sure beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onEdit trigger which uses Range.getDataValidation() and Range.setDataValidation() to copy the rule from an existing row to the new row

Comment: That is what I am thinking, but I am having trouble writing the specific code. This is what I have so far

Comment: function onEdit() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Hostel Activities'); 
  var toprow = s.getRange('A2:K2'); 
  var lastrow = s.getLastRow(); 
  
  s.getDataValidation(toprow); 
  s.setDataValidation(lastrow); 

}

Comment: You've misunderstood get and setDataValidation(). They are methds of Range https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataValidation() . So your code should be more like lastRow.setDataValidations(firstRow.getDataValidations())

Comment: I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot find function setDataValidations in object 14. (line 7, file "Code")
with this code function onEdit() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Hostel Activities'); 
  var toprow = s.getRange('A2:K2'); 
  var lastrow = s.getLastRow(); 
  
  lastrow.setDataValidations(toprow.getDataValidations()) 

} .... Thank you a ton for your assistance

Comment: getLastRow() returns the integer row number. What you need is a Range.  So use getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I think I'm getting closer, but still not there. I'm getting this error now "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 14 (line 10, file "Code")" ... I'm using this code ... function onEdit() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Hostel Activities'); 
  var toprow = s.getRange('A2:K2'); 
  var bottomrow = s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(), s.getLastColumn());

  
  bottomrow.setDataValidations(toprow.getDataValidations()) 

}  ... If you could paste in the correct code for me to try it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I can't do your coding coz I don't have your spreadsheet. The problem is that you are pasting 14 rows worth of validations into one row. s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(), s.getLastColumn()) should probably be s.getRange(1,1,1, s.getLastColumn())

Comment: That adjustment didn't seem to work...argh. Sorry for being such a bother here. Here is a link to a copy of the accessible doc. My work is in the script editor "copy of keep data validation" -> https://docs.google.com/a/hiusa.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At-NtEiXSQV8dHFJVXpkc0hfbThMMWZ5RDVuNUVmUkE#gid=9

Comment: Awesome!! - You are a champion.

Comment: One last thing - what if I wanted the validation to be applied to all or numerous rows? I noticed that because some of the content is added to the sheet through a form or the api, the script is not registering the onedit() trigger until someone goes into the sheet to make a change and by then numerous rows beyond the bottom row have been added.

Answer (score 12):

While not necessarily elegant I found the following to work:

- create  your validation on the entire column
- once that's done click the cell(s) that represent the heading, select data / validation, and then click on 'remove validation' on that single cell.

This way any newly inserted rows will inherit the validation set up on the entire column and you don't have to always be reminded that your heading isn't a valid value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a new feature but this worked. Set the validation as list from interval and interval as:

```
'sheet'!C2:C
```

This includes all new rows excluding title(first row)

Answer (score 2):

While in the data validation dialog screen you can manually enter the range as "Sheet1!A:A" to apply the formula to all of column A.

This also includes new rows added afterwards